# ... is not a known element when referencing submodule

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7 and cli. I have a very simple case where I am trying to include a submodule in the parent module.

app.module is referencing graph.module like this

```
import { GraphModule } from './components/graph/graph.module';

@NgModule({  
  imports: [
    GraphModule,
     .... other modules
```

app.component.html is using the graph component like this

```
<Graph></Graph>
```

graph.module looks like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { GraphComponent } from './graph.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    exports: [GraphComponent],
    declarations: [GraphComponent],
    providers: [],
})

export class GraphModule {
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

I am getting the following error:

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'Graph' is not a known element:
1. If 'Graph' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("h [nodes]="nodes" [links]="links" [autoZoom]="autoZoom" [autoCenter]="autoCenter"></graph> -->
    [ERROR ->]<Graph></Graph>

  <!-- </div> -->
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@7:4
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20605)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26171)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26158)
    at compiler.js:26101
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26101)
    at compiler.js:26011
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2421)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:2430
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse @ compiler.js:20605
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate @ compiler.js:26171
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ compiler.js:26158
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:26101
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.js:26101
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:26011
then @ compiler.js:2421
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:26010
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:25970
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @ core.js:17619
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:17802
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Comment: Can you show the complete app.module.ts

Comment: What's the Graph component selector? Usually, selectors are in the lower case.

Comment: Lowercase returns the same error...

Comment: You may have not a tag selector. Share the `@Component` code of your Graph component.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten thanks you can add it as the answer. I missed that part though it was generated based on the componentname.

Comment: My pleasure, @doorman! Done.

Comment: This appears to be a syntax mistake of typing `<Graph>` instead of `<graph>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cause of the issue is that your `GraphComponent` [selector](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) is not a tag selector or your component tag name is different from "Graph". I.e. it's **not**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Graph'
})
export class GraphComponent { }
```

That's why Angular can't find your component.

Check what selector your component really has to correctly use the component in your other component templates.